# My Painting is clear when my device goes into the landsape mode

Tags: android

i m just working on canvas drawing app there is an issue , when i m drawing on canvas in portrait mode and switch my device in to landscape the the my drawing is clear or removed from the canvas . Looking for any solution,advice .

Thanks & Regards ,

Utkarsh Joshi

Comment: when you orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated. You need to handle orientation change. check the docs

Comment: yes but how , i can't understand it properly

Comment: then read the docs again to understand http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect change in orientation. Once a change has been detected, re-draw the objects you need.

```
void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
    // Orientation change has been detected
    if(orientation == 0) {
        // Changed to portrait mode
    }
    else if (orientation == 90 || orientation == 270) {
        // Changed to landscape mode
        // 90 = left side 270 = right side
    }
}
```

You might find this documentation helpful http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html

Answer (score 1):

You have add attribute `android:configChanges="orientation"` to your Activity in Manifest.
And override the method `onConfigurationChanged` in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this too in your activity

```
 @Override
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
 super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 }
```

and in manifest file in your activity :

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```